# Python 3 iterate through dictionary with list values to display as table

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, python-3.5

I have a dictionary with lists stored as the values:

```
my_dict = {"version":[1, 2, 3],"size":[10, 20, 30],"cost":["£200","£350","£400"],"limit":[44, 53, 62, 71],}
```

What I would like to do is iterate through all of these to display a table:

```
version  size   cost    limit
  1       10    £200     44         
  2       20    £350     53
  3       30    £400     62
```

I know I can use the zip function like:

```
for row in zip(*([key] + (value) for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()))):
    print(*row)
```

but I want to learn how to iterate through this sort of thing without using zip. I've tested a few nested for loops and I can't get the output I want!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to iterate over the `my_dict`, but using the `zip()` is more pythonic (and convenient too):

```
my_dict = {"version":[1, 2, 3],"size":[10, 20, 30],"cost":["£200","£350","£400"],"limit":[44, 53, 62, 71],}

print(''.join('{:^15}'.format(k) for k in my_dict))

cnt = 0
while True:
    try:
        for k in my_dict:
            print('{:^15}'.format(my_dict[k][cnt]), end='')
        print()
        cnt += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Prints:

```
version         size           cost           limit     
   1             10            £200            44       
   2             20            £350            53       
   3             30            £400            62
```

---

EDIT: To specify the order of columns, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
my_dict = {"version":[1, 2, 3],"size":[10, 20, 30],"cost":["£200","£350","£400"],"limit":[44, 53, 62, 71],}

from operator import itemgetter

columns = ['version', 'cost', 'limit', 'size']

print(''.join('{:^15}'.format(k) for k in columns))

i = itemgetter(*columns)
for vals in zip(*i(my_dict)):
    print(''.join('{:^15}'.format(v) for v in vals))
```

Prints:

```
version         cost           limit          size      
   1            £200            44             10       
   2            £350            53             20       
   3            £400            62             30
```

Comment: That's great thank you! It seems to print the columns in a different order for me - size, limit, cost, version. This is why I abandoned using zip, as I couldn't order the columns. I want to be more pythonic generally is there a way of doing it but being able to order the columns as well? I'm willing to revisit zip if there's a better way of doing it with that function :)

Comment: @JamesPy I edited my answer. I see you are using Python3.5 - the dictionaries are unordered in that version. With my example, you can specify order of columns you want to print.